# Create a new shopify product with multiple variants and options

Tags: shopify

I'm trying to create a product with multiple variants and options through Shopify API. 
How should I specify the options for each variant? Can I create multiple variants with one call? Thanks!

This is my JSON:

```
 {
 "handle":"carry-bag-grey",
  "body_html":"",
  "title":"Carry Bag(GREY)",   
  "product_type":"Women",
  "vendor":"MONOFOLD",
  "variants":[ 
  {
   "price":"23", 
   "fulfillment_service":"manual",
   "grams":"0",
   "inventory_management":"shopify",
   "inventory_policy":"deny",
   "sku":"MO1404180102",
   "taxable":"FALSE",
  "requires_shipping":"TRUE",
  "inventory_quantity":"2", 
  "Size":"6"
   },
  {
  "price":"23",
  "fulfillment_service":"manual",
  "grams":"0",
  "inventory_management":"shopify",
  "inventory_policy":"deny",
  "sku":"MO1404180103",
  "taxable":"FALSE",
  "requires_shipping":"TRUE",
  "inventory_quantity":"2",
  "Size":"6"
   }
 ]
}
```

I'm getting back a `ActiveResource::ResourceInvalid (Failed.)`, does anyone know why?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can create multiple variants with one call.

[See the Shopify API docs here](http://docs.shopify.com/api/product#create):

> Create a new product with multiple product variants
>
> ```
> POST /admin/products.json
> {
>   "product": {
>     "title": "Burton Custom Freestlye 151",
>     "body_html": "<strong>Good snowboard!</strong>",
>     "vendor": "Burton",
>     "product_type": "Snowboard",
>     "variants": [
>       {
>         "option1": "First",
>         "price": "10.00",
>         "sku": 123
>       },
>       {
>         "option1": "Second",
>         "price": "20.00",
>         "sku": "123"
>       }
>     ]
>   }
> }
> ```